# Add class after scroll on variable height div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone spot the mistake in my JS syntax?

```
function setSize() {
  var headerHeight = $('#header-blue:visible').height();
  var subHeight = $('.subhead:visible').height();
  var totalHeight = headerHeight + subHeight;
  console.log(totalHeight);
}

// Set height variables on load
$(document).ready(function () {
  setSize();
});
// Set height variables on window resize
$(window).resize(totalHeight);

// Fixed header on scroll
$(function() {
    var header = $(".subhead");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= totalHeight) {
            header.addClass(" fixed");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

The goal here is to set a class when a scroll position is reached. The scroll position is variable because it depends on the height of 2 div's, which changes on mobile and desktop.

Unfortunately, I am receiving syntax errors saying totalHeight is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The variable totalHeight is only in the scope of the function setSize(), therefore it cannot be used outside the function. To solve the problem you have to make the variable global such as declaring it before the function:

```
var totalHeight;
function setSize()
```

You can also do the following:

```
var totalHeight = function(){
   //code of the function here and make it return the value
}
```

Comment: would you possibly be able to stick it in a fiddle for me??